# How can i get the first three post_id in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can i get the first three ID ONLY of the products in category with woocommerce ?

```
"<?php echo $post->ID; ?>", "<?php echo $post->ID; ?>", "<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"
```

It's works only for my first product id, i can't get the second and third products id.

Can you help me ?

Thank's in advance,

Best regards.

Comment: what does $post contain?

Comment: Where are you trying to pull them from? You need to create a query that returns a set of posts that you would then loop over in a section of code. You wouldn't manually create them as an inline piece of code like you've done above. Although you could, but you would explicitly set the desired IDs in this case. (But again, there would be almost no need to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_posts function of wordpress to achieve your goal.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'ASC', # Keep ASC for First 3 products or keep DESC for Latest 3 products as required
);
$products = get_posts($args);

foreach($products AS $product){
  echo $product->ID; # You will get different product ids here
}
```

For more details, refer https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'product_cat' => 'your_cat', 'orderby' => 'desc' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

            <div class="product">    

                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                    <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    

                </a>

                <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

            </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I hope it will work for you.